# In React, can values set in the contructor(props) be overridden? If not, how to set over writable defaults?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pretty sure I know the answer to this because my `setState({})` really isn't doing anything.

This is the contructor that I have:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        percentiles: {
            incN: 'n',
            incP1: 10,
            incP2: 25,
            incP3: 50,
            incMean: 'Mean',
            incP4: 75,
            incP5: 90,
            coN: 'n',
            coP1: 50,
            coMean: 'Mean'
        }
    }
}
```

Later on I am trying to do something like:

```
handleClick(e) {
    this.setState({
        incN: e.target.id
    })
}
```

Where `e.target.id = 5` and it isn't changing from `10`, so I am pretty sure it can't be overridden if assigned in the `constructor(props)`.

So where should I put the defaults at that *can* be overridden? In the `render()` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

incN is a property of percentiles so you would need to do:

```
this.setState({
    percentiles: {
        ...this.state.percentiles,
        incN: e.target.id
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, realized that after posting and was on my way to delete this. You are right though!